# How to bind data to ActivityListItem List view in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Hi I am a beginner in xamarin android.I want to show a text field and image field in the list view, how can I do it.

Here is my .axml code

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:paddingTop="1dip" 
      android:paddingBottom="1dip" 
      android:paddingLeft="6dip" 
      android:paddingRight="6dip">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" 
        android:layout_width="24dip" 
        android:layout_height="24dip" /> 
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:paddingLeft="6dip" /> 
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this your `ListView`'s item layout?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/xamarin/listview-example-in-xamarin-android), it is about how to use listview in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Do you mean a listview or your LinearLayout?

Comment: if you are only learning I would also suggest looking at RecyclerView as an alternative to listview and deciding between the two which is best for your project

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Thanks for the link